# import issue with python/django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the `calendar` module in my Django views.py file. If I make the import at the top of the file, with the rest of my package imports, and call the `monthrange` function on the module, I get the following:

> 'function' has no attribute 'monthrange'

If however I import the module in my function, where I make use of `monthrange` it works fine.

This has left me scratching my head. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the code in the same manner in both scenarios? First thing I usually check is your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like namespace clash - maybe 'calendar' got redefined some place as a variable or function name.

Try to import monthrange from calendar at the top of the module, 'monthrange' is much less likely to clash with a variable or function elsewhere the code.

```
from calendar import monthrange
```

Comment: As far as namespace clashing goes, I'm importing calendar in another file which is being imported in views.py - could that be causing the issue?

Comment: `from somemodule import *` is evil.

Comment: @Michael: yes, this is a circular dependency issue rather than a namespace clash.

Comment: @Daniel: If that's the case, shouldn't I be able to just use `calendar` in my views.py without explicitly importing it?

Comment: @Michael what? you still need to import a function before you can use it in a particular file.

Comment: @Daniel: I was asking that if I'm importing `calendar` in forms.py and then doing `from forms.py import *` in my views.py, should I be able to use `calendar` without explicitly importing it in views.py?